# Docker For Mac Beta16 Error: Pinata Command Not Found

Tags: docker

I've been seeing the use of Pinata in a lot of instructions for the Docker for Mac beta. However, using pinata at the Terminal yields a "command not found: pinata" error.

This [user on the Docker forums](https://forums.docker.com/t/pinata-command-not-found/15245) is reporting the same issue, but there's no resolution. Does anyone have any tips on what to do?

System info:
OSX 10.11.5
Version 1.12.0-rc2-beta16 (build: 9493)

Answer (score 5):

Pinata was removed and some of the preferences were moved to the GUI.

A hacky way to change some settings. From [the forum](https://forums.docker.com/t/pinata-missing-in-latest-mac-beta-1-11-2-beta15/15541/22) :

```
cd ~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/database/com.docker.driver.amd64-linux
echo '{"storage-driver":"aufs","dns":["8.8.8.8"],"insecure-registries":["yourdomain.com:5000"],"debug":true}' > etc/docker/daemon.json
git add etc/docker/daemon.json;
git commit -m 'etc/docker/daemon.json change';
```

The git commit will trigger an xhyve VM restart (git commit hook?). The Docker for Mac menulet icon in OS X will show a restart.

The Docker for Mac preferences will now show yourdomain.com:5000 as an insecure registry.

docker run -it --rm busybox cat /etc/resolv.conf will show that the nameserver for containers is now 8.8.8.8

Comment: if `com.docker.driver.amd64-linux ` folder is not present, you might need to perform a git reset first, `cd ~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/database/` then `git reset --hard`